# Two ASP.NET MVC websites in one: shared logics, different designs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best approach to keeping two separate sets of views in one application?

I need to create two websites which have different frontend layouts, but have almost identical code base (admin area, controller logic, etc). There are supposed to be two build configurations that decide which layout to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into the concept of using [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) for organizing your project

With Areas you can blend your logic and separate it as you wish. Areas have their own front end by having a separate Views directory (although you can have multiple Areas use a common layout).

Comment: Is it possible to avoid duplicating controllers between areas?

Comment: You could use base controllers and put there what you need, but i would avoid it due to coupling..You could create your functionality in a a separate library and reuse your logic in your controllers...

Comment: On the other hand if you dont need different functionality but only different view layout, dont use areas and use different layout file between views...

Comment: The entire set of views is different, not only the main layout. There are about 40 pages, blocks and other parts. But the controllers are absolutely identical.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/how-to-render-different-layout-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is which layout will be used. You could set this as an AppSetting in your Web.config and then create different configurations for each site. In `Views\_ViewStart.cshtml` you can pull the layout path from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. When publishing, you simply choose which configuration you want to publish, and then use the configuration-specific web.config transform to change the AppSetting appropriately.